# ¿Como puedo calcular el "Total General" de una tabla con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estoy calculando unas cantidades con precio unitario y subtotales. El problema está cuando quiero calcular el "Total General". Así va mi código:

```
    function multiplicar() {
    var quantity = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity');
    var price = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
    var subtotals = document.querySelectorAll('.subtotal');
    var totals = document.querySelectorAll('.totals');

    for(var i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++){ 
      subtotals[i].value = quantity[i].value * price[i].value;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < subtotals.length; i++){ 
      totals[i].value = subtotals[i].value;
    }

  }
```

Esas últimas líneas de código no me funcionan como pensé.  Los cálculos de quantity y  price están perfectos pero al sumar los subtotales no me muestra el calculo en:

```
<input type="text" name="total" class="totals">
```

He estado haciendo pruebas y ahora estoy más cerca. Lo que he hecho es agregar una nueva funcion llamada suma() que se ejecuta si hay cambios en los subtotales y ahora me muestra resultados en .total pero no los suma si no que los agrega; es decir 1 + 1 no es 2 sino que resulta 11.

El nuevo código va así:

```javascript
 function multiplicar() {
    var quantity = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity');
    var price = document.querySelectorAll('.price');
    var subtotals = document.querySelectorAll('.subtotal');
   
    for(var i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++){ 
      subtotals[i].value = quantity[i].value * price[i].value;
    }

  }

    function sumar() {
    var subtotal1 = document.querySelectorAll('#subtotal1');
    var subtotal2 = document.querySelectorAll('#subtotal2');
    var totals = document.querySelectorAll('.total');
   
    for(var i = 0; i < subtotal1.length; i++){ 
      totals[i].value = subtotal1[i].value + subtotal2[i].value;
    }

  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="subtotal" id="subtotal1" onchange="sumar()">
<input type="text" class="subtotal" id="subtotal2" onchange="sumar()">
<input type="text" class="totals">
```

**Solución:**

He logrado obtener lo que necesitaba convirtiendo los valores de subtotal1 y subtotal2 en números, quedando las últimas líneas de la siguiente manera:

```
for(var i = 0; i < subtotal1.length; i++){ 
  totals[i].value = Number(subtotal1[i].value) + Number(subtotal2[i].value);
}
```

Gracias a la comunidad y muy especialmente a @Alfabravo y @AlfaRojo por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuál es el problema con ese código? Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Estás armando un valor total sumando todos los subtotales? la pregunta es entonces por qué armas un array que tiene los mismos valores que los subtotales en vez de sumar? No sabemos cómo estás intentando pintar totals ahí pero seguro no funciona porque es un array...

Comment: El problema que se presenta es que no sé como sumar los subtotales.

Comment: Agrega como en `20 + 42` queda `2042` ? Trata siempre de dar datos de prueba, resultado actual y resultado esperado. COdificar a ciegas no es cool :)

Comment: El subtotal lo igualas en cada interacción, tienes que ir sumando el resultado, al resultado que ya tenias... `subtotals[i].value += quantity[i].value * price[i].value;`

Comment: Correcto @Alfabravo los agrega, es decir 2 + 2 no es 4 sino 22.

Comment: @AlfaRojo ahí no está el problema, de echo esa parte funciona muy bien.

Comment: Tenés que parsear las variables a numéricas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como respuesta a la pregunta completa:

- Estabas generando un array de totales[i] y asignándole a cada posición, el contenido de subtotales[i] en un for. Eso sólo te iba a generar un duplicado del array de subtotales y no estabas sumando nada.
- Para lo último, es importante que te familiarices con los detalles de JavaScript. Hay [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Strings) que te puede ayudar a entender cómo funciona un lenguaje. En este caso, es claro que está tratando los valores como Strings, así que debes convertirlos en números para que el operador `+` haga algo.

Si usas `Number(un_string)`, obtendrás el valor numérico correspondiente y ya podrás hacer operaciones aritméticas con él. Revisa cómo estabas generando los subtotales, porque es muy posible que tengas el mismo problema!

Comment: sin duda debo documentarme más sobre JavaScript. Este comentario me ha ayudado mucho. La solución estaba en Number()

Comment: @FélixEduardoLeónSosa si la respuesta te resolvió tus dudas, márcala como aceptada. Me alegra poder ayudar